# HashMap returning null values

Tags: java, hashmap

Hey guys this is my code In the loop when i put    mapTable.get("NN"). It is giving the correct value but in the print statement outside the loop it is giving null. pls help.

```
Map<String,String> mapTable=new HashMap<String,String>();
    while((line2=br1.readLine())!=null)
    {
        if((!line2.trim().isEmpty())&&Character.isDigit(line2.charAt(0)))
        {
        String[] tmp=line2.split("\t");
        mapTable.put(tmp[1].trim(),tmp[2].trim());
        System.out.println("MAP-----"+tmp[1]+ " ->  "+tmp[2]+" ex "+mapTable.get("NN"));
        }   
    }
    printMap(mapTable);
    System.out.println("CHECKING-------> "+mapTable.get("NN"));


This is the output:

MAP-----NN  ->  n ex n
MAP-----NNS  ->  n ex n
MAP-----NNP  ->  n ex n
MAP-----NNPS  ->  n ex n
MAP-----PDT  ->   ex n
and so on..
JJ = adj
NN = n
WRB = adv
LS = 
PRP = prp
DT = dt
FW = pw

CHECKING-------> null
```

PrintMap function:

```
    public static void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of variable line2?

Comment: How your printMap() method looks like?

Comment: @pankajtiwari can you post your printMap() function?

Comment: `printMap` change it to `clearMap`.

Comment: @PankajTiwari You are not prinitng the map. You are clearing it using the method remove()

Comment: @RonaldRandon why do not you post up your answer with good explanation so Other can vote u up?

Comment: @KickButtowski Thanks for your suggestion. Just did that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove line:

```
it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
```

In this line you are removing all elements from map.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void printMap(Map mp) {
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

In the above method, you are trying to iterate the map and print it. But the line

> it.remove();

will delete the Entry from the map.
After clearing all the Entry, you are trying to get the value for the key "NN" which is not in the map. Thats why you are getting `null` value. Please remove the line `it.remove()` in the `printMap()` method.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I think it is "NN" not 'NN'?

Comment: Yes. Just for highlighting the key I used single quotes. Thanks for correcting.